# find order of function -

Tags: group-theory

Let $f(n) = x$, where $x^x = n$. Find order of function $f$.

And it is strange for me. Why ? Firslty, I don't see any group. 
Ok, but look at my reasoning.

What is definition of order ?
$ord(a) = \min(\{k : a^k =1\})$

Thus, $f^3 =f\circ f\circ f $ 
So: $(f\circ  f\circ f)(n) = f(f(f(n))) = f(f(x)) $
But I get $f(x)$ - what is it ? $f(x)$  ? I don't know.

My friends, help me please understand this subject :(

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: there is no information.

Comment: Maybe by "order" the exercise means the [asymptotic family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) it belongs to? Or maybe [this definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FunctionOrder.html) is applicable in the context?

Comment: "exercise means the asymptotic family it belongs to?"  Oh,yes. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what does "order" mean here, but
$$f(n)=\frac{\ln n}{W(\ln n)},$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), and of course $W$ means both $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$.

To give more details.

$$x^x = n \implies x \ln x = \ln n \implies e^{\ln x} \cdot \ln x = \ln n \implies \ln x = W(\ln n) \implies x=e^{W(\ln n)},$$

which means

$$x=\frac{\ln n}{W(\ln n)},$$

since $\ln n = W(\ln n) e^{W(\ln n)}$ by the definition of Lambert W function.

To give check it.

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\ln n}{W(\ln n)}\right)^{\left(\frac{\ln n}{W(\ln n)}\right)} & = n \\
\frac{\ln n}{W(\ln n)} \cdot \left( \ln \ln n - \ln W(\ln n) \right) & = \ln n \\
\ln \ln n & = \ln W(\ln n) + W(\ln n) \\
\ln n & = W( \ln n ) \cdot e^{W( \ln n )},
\end{align}
$$

and this satisfies the definition of Lambert W function.

After that we have to find bounds for $W$. In this [paper](http://rgmia.org/papers/v10n2/lambert-v2.pdf) Theorem 2.1. will help us.

For every $x \geq e$, we have

$$\ln x - \ln \ln x \leq W(x) \leq \ln x - \frac{1}{2} \ln \ln x,$$

with equality holding only for $x=e$. The coefficients $-1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ of $\ln \ln x$ both are best possible for the range $x \geq e$.

At last you have to find bounds for $W \circ \ln$, and that will answer the question.

Comment: What is it  ? What do you mean ?

Comment: @xawey: This is the explicit form of your function. Look at example 2 of the Wiki page (with $z=n$).

Comment: But the task is find an asymptotic family

Comment: Sure. And how will you find it without it? I think you will need this, to get an answer.